# MVC delete parent after all children have been linked to other parents

Tags: model-view-controller

I have this scenario to implement: a collection of parentEntities, each parentEntity having zero to  childEntities. I need to implement a multiple-delete form (checked parentEntities will be deleted), with this rule: if a parentEntity has children, it can be deleted only after all its children have been linked to other parentEntities.

So I have the Index form for the parents, and on submit I post to the "Delete" action. For each checked parent, if it has zero children I delete it, else I redirect to children edit view. When there is no more child linked to the initial parent, I must return to the parents "Delete" action and continue from where I left (delete the current parent whose children I just re-affected, then delete the next checked parent).

My problem is: **HOW do I write the return from children edit to the parents delete?**

I use:
`return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Parents", action = "Index", page, IDsToDelete = idCollection }));`

but I get the error:

> http://localhost:64209/Parents/Delete?page=0; The resource cannot be found.

Thank you for helping.
Manu

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's solved - I just needed to pass the string of checked items pending for delete.